# How to nest groovy sql result sets and generate JSON for same?

Tags: sql, groovy

In my DB , i have Order and corresponding line .I want to generate JSON for each order using groovy and wrote below piece of code but it is not working as expected.

```
def OrderResultSet=conn.rows('select ORDER_NUMBER,COMPANY_NAME from ORDERS where ORDER_NUMBER=74')
OrderResultSet.each{ 
    def LineResultset=conn.rows('select * from LINE where HEADER_ID=:ORDER_NUMBER',[ORDER_NUMBER:it.ORDER_NUMBER])
}
```

How to link both result set and generate JSON as below:

```
{  
   "ORDER_NUMBER":7493767,
   "COMPANY_NAME":"WWT",
   "LINE":[  
      {  
         "HEADER_ID":7493767,
         "LINE_ID":12,
         "INSTALLSITE_ID":22,
         "TEXT":"world"
      },
      {  
         "HEADER_ID":7493767,
         "LINE_ID":11,
         "INSTALLSITE_ID":21,
         "TEXT":"hello"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: which db  (mysql,sql server) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def OrderResultSet=conn.rows('select ORDER_NUMBER,COMPANY_NAME from ORDERS where ORDER_NUMBER=74')
OrderResultSet.each{ 
    it.LINE=conn.rows('select * from LINE where HEADER_ID=:ORDER_NUMBER',[ORDER_NUMBER:it.ORDER_NUMBER])
}

println new JsonBuilder(OrderResultSet).toPrettyString()
```